# Data Filter Expression in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to filter data in Azure Data Flow.
However, I do not know how to do this.
What I want to do is to extract only the records with the largest value in the "seq_no" column among those with duplicate IDs.
I just don't know what function to use to achieve this.
I await your answer.
Any answer would be appreciated.
Sorry for my bad English, I am Japanese.
Thanks for reading.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use **aggregate transform** and group by id and take the max(seq_no).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **aggregate transform** and group by id and take the max(seq_no). I repro'd the same. Below are the steps.

- Sample data is taken as input.

| id | seq_no | mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | 10 |
| 1001 | 1 | 10 |
| 1001 | 2 | 20 |
| 1002 | 1 | 30 |
| 1002 | 2 | 20 |
| 1002 | 3 | 10 |

[image]
img:1 Source Transformation data preview

- Then Aggregate transform is taken. In Aggregate settings,
  `id` is given as group by column and aggregates expression is given for `seq_no` column as `max(seq_no)`.

[image: gif111]

- Aggregate transform output data

[image]
img:2 Data preview of Aggregate transform.

- In order to get the other column data corresponding to maximum of `seq_no` column, **Join transformation** is used.

```
Left stream: aggregate1
Right stream: source1
Join Type:Inner
Join conditions: source1@id==source2@id
                 source1@seq_no==source2@seq_no
```

[image]
img:3 Join Transformation settings

[image]
img:4 Join transformation data preview

- Select transformation is used and removed the extra columns.
  [image: gif112]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried this, but in fact there are 33 other columns, and this method seems to erase them, leaving only "id" and "seq_no".
Is there any solution?

Comment: What value should come in remaining columns? Can you share the sample input and output data with few additional columns?

Comment: I added the info.
I've hidden the content because it contains personal information.

Comment: If this is the input data [input img](https://i.imgur.com/Nn5bTdT.png), how will be the output

Comment: Output only the record with the largest seq_no, leaving all other columns.

Comment: You can use join transformation and get all column data. Check the edited answer